# Shared Access Signature not working in Azure Files with subfolders

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-files, azure-files

*(Updated below with answer)*
I had a working program that stores PDFs in an Azure Files 'reports' share([domain].file.core.windows.net/reports). After the file is stored, I immediately get a Shared Access Signature for the file, concatenate it onto the physical file name and store the result on a record of the report transaction.

```cs
//create the storage location if it doesn't exist
var shareRoot = _blob.CreateCloudFileClient().GetShareReference("reports").GetRootDirectoryReference();

//get reference to azure file and copy the PDF report stream to it
CloudFile cloudFile = GetCloudFile("reports", storedFileName);
using (CloudFileStream strm = await cloudFile.OpenWriteAsync(stream.Length))
{ 
    await stream.CopyToAsync(strm); 
}

//get SAS using stored policy and create stored file name
string token = cloudFile.GetSharedAccessSignature(null, "myPolicy");
token = new Uri(cloudFile.StorageUri.PrimaryUri.ToString() + token).ToString();

// function to centralize calls for files  
private CloudFile GetCloudFile(string fileShare, string fileName)
{
    // Parse the connection string and get a reference to storage file
    //See UPDATE below: ***THIS WAS THE PROBLEM*****
    return _blob.CreateCloudFileClient().GetShareReference(fileShare).GetRootDirectoryReference().GetFileReference(fileName);
}
```

An example of stored file access string from old code: 
https://[domain].file.core.windows.net/reports/[filename].pdf?sv=2018-03-28&sr=f&si=myPolicy&sig=Wd1BkHPRTPHDiezA%2FWe4CD4mOJIyILxDUXxrxjH1byU%3D

At any time I could paste that URL into a browser and call up the PDF.

All worked well until I there were too many reports to scroll through in the 'reports' directory, so I modified the program to create subfolders in the 'reports' directory based upon month (e.g., '201902'). The physical file location is now [domain].file.core.windows.net/reports/201902. I modified the code to add the subfolder and store the file in it:

```cs
//create the storage location if it doesn't exist -- same as before
var shareRoot = _blob.CreateCloudFileClient().GetShareReference("reports").GetRootDirectoryReference();
//create new subfolder if needed
await shareRoot.GetDirectoryReference("201902").CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

//get reference to azure file in subfolder and copy the PDF report stream to it
CloudFile cloudFile = GetCloudFile("reports/201902", storedFileName);
```

From that point forward, the token string can no longer access the PDF.

An example of stored file access string from new code:
https://[domain].file.core.windows.net/reports/201902/[filename].pdf?sv=2018-03-28&sr=f&si=myPolicy&sig=YZ64hSk5IKQOs%2BhgACfBlQk%2F6r8OqiA7D8DBv%2F3G%2FyA%3D

When I paste that string into the address bar, what comes back is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Error>
    <Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
    <Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. RequestId:e51d0e3c-e01a-003e-27bf-c49bf8000000 Time:2019-02-14T23:46:20.4325820Z</Message>
    <AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature did not match. String to sign used was /file/[domain]/reports/201902/[filename].pdf myPolicy 2018-03-28 </AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>
```

No other changes were made--the access key is the same, etc. If I navigate to the file in Azure Portal, it is indeed stored in reports/201902 with the filename I specified. I can download it from the portal with no problem (but the portal generates its own SAS token, so that doesn't help).

Thinking it might have something to do with stored policy (myPolicy), I generated a new one and tried it but nothing changed. The policy is stored at the share root (reports) rather than the subfolder (reports/201902) because there's no way to specify a policy at the subfolder level.

If anyone has any suggestions, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Can you edit the question and include the code for your `GetCloudFile` function?

Comment: Thanks for the right question, Gaurav!

Comment: @GDeM - I'm glad you solved your own issue and answer it, but... the answer belongs as a *proper answer*, not as an edit to the question (the edit itself is invalid). I was going to just roll-back your edit but, seeing that you put a bunch of work into documenting it, *please* post a proper answer, and then delete the answer from your original question.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE WITH THE ANSWER**

As correctly surmised by Gaurav Mantri, the problem was in the GetCloudFile method, where I wasn't even looking.  It was getting a reference to the root 'reports' directory instead of the subfolder '201902' when it created the file.  By explicitly specifying 'reports/201902' in the filename to be stored, Azure was putting the file in the right place but the SAS was being written against the root 'reports' share and not the '201902' subfolder. So there would never be any way to call up the file because the physical URI was correct but the security would never match.

The new code is shown below.  Thanks to Gaurav for asking the right question.

New code that works:

```cs
//UPDATED: moved folder creation to GetCloudFile method

//UPDATED: get reference to azure file and copy the PDF report stream to it
CloudFile cloudFile = await GetCloudFile(REPORT_SHARE, fPath, storedFileName);
using (CloudFileStream strm = await cloudFile.OpenWriteAsync(stream.Length))
{ 
    await stream.CopyToAsync(strm); 
}

//get SAS using stored policy and create stored file name
string token = cloudFile.GetSharedAccessSignature(null, "myPolicy");
token = new Uri(cloudFile.StorageUri.PrimaryUri.ToString() + token).ToString();

// UPDATED: method to get the cloud file to store uploads and reports  
private async Task<CloudFile> GetCloudFile(string shareRoot, string shareFolder, string fileName)
{
    //create the subpath if it doesn't exist
    var sRoot = _blob.CreateCloudFileClient().GetShareReference(shareRoot).GetRootDirectoryReference();
    await sRoot.GetDirectoryReference(shareFolder).CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

    //create and return the file reference
    return sRoot.GetDirectoryReference(shareFolder).GetFileReference(fileName);
}
```